# Restrict WooCommerce related products only to their sub-categories (last category - without child)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I already  tried this code and worked for me correctly:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts', 'my_custom_related_products' );
function custom_related_products($product){
    global $woocommerce;
    // Related products are found from category and tag
    $tags_array = array(0);
    $cats_array = array(0);
    // Get tags
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_tag');
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) $tags_array[] = $term->term_id;
    // Get categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ){
        $check_for_children = get_categories(array('parent' => $term->term_id, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'));
        if(empty($check_for_children)){
            $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    // Don't bother if none are set
    if ( sizeof($cats_array)==1 && sizeof($tags_array)==1 ) return array();
    // Meta query
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();
    $meta_query   = array_filter( $meta_query );
    // Get the posts
    $related_posts = get_posts( array(
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
            'tax_query'      => array(
                'relation'      => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                    'field'        => 'id',
                    'terms'        => $cats_array
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
                    'field'        => 'id',
                    'terms'        => $tags_array
                )
            )
        ) );
    $related_posts = array_diff( $related_posts, array( $product->id ), $product->get_upsells() );
    return $related_posts;
}
```

but if i have some product in Sports > Nike > Shoes, it shows related product in "Nike" and not in "Shoes". I need to randomly show related product in single product page with same sub-category (last category - without child - ex "Shoes")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your above codes with follows code snippet to achieve your above tasks -

```
function wc_related_products_by_last_available_depth_term( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    $hierarchy = array();
    $cat_id = '';
    // find the depth of terms
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
        if( $ancestors && count( $ancestors ) > 1 ) {
            $hierarchy[$term->term_id] = max($ancestors);
        }elseif( $ancestors ) {
            $hierarchy[$term->term_id] = $ancestors[0];
        }
        $cat_id = $term->term_id;
    }
    // if level of depth term available replace $cat_id
    if( $hierarchy ){
       $cat_id = max( array_keys( $hierarchy ) );
    }

    $related_posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'exclude' => array( $product_id ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                'field'        => 'id',
                'terms'        => array( $cat_id )
            )
        )
    ));
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'wc_related_products_by_last_available_depth_term', 99, 3 );
```

Code goes to your active theme's functions.php